# Symfony - run console command on kernel.terminate

Tags: console, symfony, background-process, shell-exec

I have configured swiftmailer to spool emails using file type. here is my swiftmailer config

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:
        type: file
        path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/spool"
```

When I send any emails it perfectly spools. I run following command to dispatch emails thereafter.

```
bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev
```

According to Symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html#spool-using-files)

```
the console command should be triggered by a cron job or scheduled task and run at a regular interval.
```

My problem is, I cannot use crontab because cron can be configured with a minimum of 1 minute interval which I cannot afford. I want to make use of the background process with immediate execution after the response is sent back to browser, hence minimizing execution of spools to bare minimum.

I attempted to solve this problem by creating an event listener class and listening to `kernel.terminate`, and execute the command using `shell_exec` or `exec` function, here is the code for reference.

```
app.kernel.terminate.listener:
        arguments: ["@kernel"]
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\KernelTerminateListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate }
```

Here is my EventListener class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\PostResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Cocur\BackgroundProcess\BackgroundProcess;

class KernelTerminateListener
{
    protected $kernel;

    protected $console;

    public function __construct($kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        $this->console = $this->kernel->getRootDir().'/../bin/console ';
    }

    public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $command = $this->console.'swiftmailer:spool:send --env='.$this->kernel->getEnvironment();
        shell_exec($command);
    }
}
```

What I am trying in here is to run `bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev` on `kernel.terminate` event, unfortunately this does not work, any hint on how to approach this problem is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What does mean 'this does not work' ?

Comment: It does not dispatch the email, whereas If i echo `$command` and copy paste it in terminal, it works. I can see that even though it gets executed, spool files are not processed, usually spool files gets deleted if it gets processed, and In my case it is not deleting.

Comment: What is the output of `shell_exec($command);` , may be a right problem ?

Comment: It comes empty,  but if i try other command such as `shell_exec('ls')` it prints me files of the directory.

Comment: This code worked for me `exec('/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.6/bin/php '.$this->kernel->getRootDir().'/../bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env='.$this->kernel->getEnvironment().' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &')` as you see, when I added absolute path for PHP it works but if I just use php in the beginning it does not.

Comment: Try using `realpath($this->kernel->getRootDir().'/..'). '/bin/console '`

Comment: Nope, it does not work, I think I understand why, in my Mac, I have two PHP installed, one that comes with Mac, and I am using MAMP, my webserver is configured to use the PHP version from MAMP, whereas commandline comes from inbuilt php, perhaps changing PHP path in command line will work. let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the memory spool type of swift mailer, it does exactly what you want

> When you use spooling to store the emails to memory, they will get sent right before the kernel terminates. **This means the email only gets sent if the whole request got executed** without any unhandled exception or any errors. To configure swiftmailer with the memory option, use the following configuration:

Comment: If you read carefully, it says, it gets executed right before the kernel terminated, this does not mean that it runs in background, it just says that It is run last, I have tried this and unfortunately this does not meet my requirement :-)

Comment: before the kernel terminated = kernel.terminate event = after the response was sent to the client and fastcgi_finish_request() was called

Comment: You are right, I found multiple references that explains what you are trying to say, unfortunately it didn't work for me perhaps because of the reason explained in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719821/response-returned-only-after-kernel-terminate-event thank you for pointing me to right direction. +1

Comment: As it says in here - "Internally, the HttpKernel makes use of the fastcgi_finish_request PHP function. This means that at the moment, only the PHP FPM server API is able to send a response to the client while the server's PHP process still performs some tasks. With all other server APIs, listeners to kernel.terminate are still executed, but the response is not sent to the client until they are all completed."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using shel_exec make use of process component,which will create a new process and command will be executed after response is sent.
shel_exec or exec will execute under same process which forces kernal to wait for completing request(because once parent process killed,child also terminates). Process component will create a new process,under that command will be executed.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
....
....
....

public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event)
{
  $command = $this->console.'swiftmailer:spool:send --env=.'$this->kernel->getEnvironment().'> output.log 2> out.log &';
  $process = new Process($command);
  $process->run();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps It was an issue with PHP, I am using MAMP and OSX comes pre-installed with PHP, basically, I got two php version installed, and for some reason, when I gave correct PHP path it worked, here is my updated listener class which I renamed to MailerSpoolListener

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\PostResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Cocur\BackgroundProcess\BackgroundProcess;

class MailerSpoolListener
{
    protected $kernel;

    protected $php;

    protected $console;

    protected $env;

    protected $command;

    protected $muteOutput;

    public function __construct($kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        $this->php = PHP_BINDIR.'/php';
        $this->command = 'swiftmailer:spool:send';
        $this->console = $this->kernel->getRootDir().'/../bin/console';
        $this->env = $this->kernel->getEnvironment();
        $this->muteOutput = '> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';
    }

    public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $command = $this->php.' '.$this->console.' '.$this->command.' --env='.$this->env.' '.$this->muteOutput;
        $process = shell_exec($command);
    }
}
```